# SQL WHERE Subquery in Field List

Tags: sql, subquery, fieldlist

I have query like:

```
SELECT field
FROM table
WHERE
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM table2
        WHERE table2.field = table.field
    )
    !=
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM table3
        WHERE table3.field = table.field
    )
```

Now I want to have those `WHERE` subqueries in my field list like:

```
SELECT field, count1, count2
FROM table
WHERE
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM table2
        WHERE table2.field = table.field
    ) AS Count1
    !=
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM table3
        WHERE table3.field = table.field
    ) AS Count2
```

Is this possible? Of course I could put those subqueries in the field list, but then I can't compare them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this if you use `Sql Server`:

```
SELECT field, ca2.c2, ca3.c3
FROM table t
cross apply(SELECT COUNT(*) c2
            FROM table2 t2
            WHERE t2.field = t.field)ca2
cross apply(SELECT COUNT(*) c3
            FROM table3 t3
            WHERE t3.field = t.field)ca3
where ca2.c2 <> ca1.c1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use correlated sub-selects to count. Wrap up in a derived table:

```
select dt.* from
(
SELECT field,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM table2
        WHERE table2.field = table.field) as cnt1,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM table3
        WHERE table3.field = table.field) as cnt2
FROM table
) dt
where dt.cnt1 <> dt.cnt2
```

Comment: I was going to suggest the exact same thing, but I thing that giorgi's answer might have better performance.

Comment: Depends on the DBMS used? (No dbms specified...)

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Is there really a difference between both versions? I would assume it's exactly the same plan (otherwise the optimizer is quite stupid)

Comment: It's more a hunch, really. I didn't test it, but sub queries are notorious for bad performance, so... but then again, this should be tested (perhaps by the OP) note that I wrote "might have better performance" (and also thing instead of think, but that's just bs...)

Comment: @ZoharPeled: A Correlated Subquery is still a Correlated Subquery if you do it within `
SELECT` or  `CROSS APPLY`  :-)

Comment: Got it. I've confused cross apply with inner join... thanks for your explanation :-)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a Derived Table:

```
select *
from
 (
   SELECT field, 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM table2
        WHERE table2.field = table.field
    ) AS Count1,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM table3
        WHERE table3.field = table.field
    ) AS Count2
   FROM table
 ) dt
WHERE Count1 <> Count2
```

Comment: You miss a comma after AS Count1

Comment: @jarlh: cut&paste :-)